# How to use an entry widget from file 1 for a class in file 2, then use that class back in file 1 in a different frame without circular reference

Tags: python, tkinter

this may sound confusing but I am trying to understand how I can get the input used in an entry widget in my main.py file and import what the user typed into another file. In the second file there would be a class that takes that data and stores it for docxtpl. Then once that is done in the main.py file there is a button that will start and write it to the docx.

I'm thinking this is more of a logic issue as I'm not really sure how to make it work without making the function all in one file. The reasoning for two separate files is I'm trying to improve my coding without relying on dumping everything into a single file.

The code looks like this

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from gui_class import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = LabelFrame(root).pack
username = Label(frame1, text="Enter your name").pack()

username_entry = Entry(frame1)
username_entry.pack()

button_Frame = LabelFrame(root).pack
mybtn = Button(button_Frame, text="Enter", command=lambda: start(button_Frame)).pack

main.loop
```

gui_class.py

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("test.docx")

def start(button_Frame)
   context = {
      "NAME" : username_entry.get()
   }

doc.render(context)
doc.save("test1.docx")
```

I get the error "username_entry is not defined" which makes sense after looking into it, it seems that gui_class.py is loaded up first before username_entry is ever created. I've only found that you can delay it by x seconds which wouldn't be a fix. I also tried importing the specific entry widget but that causes circular reference error.

I'm not entirely sure how else to solve this issue without adding the function into main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main.py`.

- Missing brace bracket for `pack`
- Added StringVar(). And put this `textvariable=var` in `Entry`
- In line 14,  Added keyword command button `var.get()` instead of
  `button_Frame`.
  Typo `main.loop` should be `mainloop()`

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from gui_class import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()

frame1 = LabelFrame(root).pack()
username = Label(frame1, text="Enter your name").pack()

username_entry = Entry(frame1, textvariable=var)
username_entry.pack()

button_Frame = LabelFrame(root).pack()
mybtn = Button(button_Frame, text="Enter", command=lambda : start(var.get()))
mybtn.pack()

mainloop()
```

And `gui_class.py`,  you can't called `username_entry.get()`.

- Replace  `username_entry.get()` to `button_Frame`

Code:
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

```
doc = DocxTemplate("test.docx")

def start(button_Frame):
   context = {
      "NAME" : button_Frame
   }
   print(context)

doc.render(context)
doc.save("test1.docx")
```

Btw, I do not used `docxtpl` library. I can do workaround.

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot after clicking. And you can see in debug:

[image]